# Fnd 2nd occourance of a string in a Memo Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a memo field called "Worklog". 
My table name is: MissingT. 
I would like to run a query which can find a specific string and get the next 6 digits following that specific string.

The string would look like below:

```
Status: Work in Progress
 Submitted: December 5, 2014 - 8:44:53 AM EST
 Approval Status: Approved
 Date Approved: December 5, 2014 - 8:44:53 AM EST
  
 SECTION 1 - REQUESTER PROFILE
 User ID: xxx111
 Name: Some, Name
 Phone #: 999-999-999
 Region: Canada
  
 SECTION 2 - AUTHORIZED INDIVIDUAL PROFILE
 User ID: xxx222
 Name: Some, name2
 Phone #:999-999-9999
 Title: Manager
```

I want the query to get the user id under section 2. My current query finds the User ID under section 1 and gets the 6 strings following it (xxx111). How can I move the query to get the 2nd occurrence of string "User ID" and the 6 strings following it.

```
UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.AuthManager = mid([Worklog],(InStr([Worklog],'User ID: ')+8),7)
WHERE (((MissingT.[worklog]) Like  "*" & 'User ID:' & "*"  ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure how efficient this could be, however I would suggest you to have a play around with this.

```
UPDATE 
    MissingT 
SET 
    MissingT.AuthManager = SplSplit([Worklog], 'User ID: ', 1, 7)
WHERE 
    MissingT.[worklog] Like  "*User ID:*";
```

The SplSplit is a UDF, which is something like,

```
Public Function SplSplit(inpStr As String, _
                         findStr As String, _
                         inVar As Integer, _
                         lenVar As Integer)

    SplSplit = Left(Split(inpStr, findStr)(inVar), lenVar)

    'If you want it to be ONE based then change it to the following. 
    'SplSplit = Left(Split(inpStr, findStr)(inVar+1), lenVar)'
End Function
```

**inpStr** is the Memo String you pass, **findStr** is the string patter you want to use to break it into multiple sections, **inVar** is the location of the data you are looking for, finally **lenVar** is the length you need to collect.

**NOTE**: The inVar is still ZERO based, if you want ONE based, then change the **inVar** as **inVar + 1** in the code.

The Split function will break the huge memo field into smaller chunks of data, based on the identifier, in your case 'User ID: '. Since we are only concerned about the second User ID, we simply use that index (as Split give a zero based array of split data).

The correct solution however; would be to forget about this horrendous Memo field and create a log table with appropriate status code and fields.

Comment: When I tried to run this, I get syntax error. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably Split function is not accessed the way VBA does in code, I have moved it into a User Defined Function, see if that helps.

Comment: SplSplit = Left(Split(inpStr, findStr)(inVar+1), lenVar)' This function did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you have it working, but please reconsider your design. You should be able to do a lot more with simple restructuring.