# Update a date field

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, vba

Date Field Name: EmailDate, 
Table Name: MissingT, 
Memo Field Name: Worklog.

I am trying to query the worklog and find a word "Effective date: " and get the rest of the characters on that same line following "Effective date: ". Then update "EmailDate" field with it.

```
UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.Emaildate = mid([Worklog],(InStr(1,[Worklog],'Effective Date: ')+16),13)
WHERE (((MissingT.[worklog]) Like  "*" & 'Effective Date: ' & "*" ));
```

I am getting a conversion error message.

Also, is there anyway to search the Worklog memo field from bottom up, rather than from top down?. I created another field called "TempD" and get the date in there first. So the date in TempD filed would look like "Wed, Dec 3, 2014". Then I did the query to update the emaildate with cdate function as below:   UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.emaildate = cdate(Format(Right([tempd],4) & "/" & Mid([tempd],6,3) & "/" & Mid([tempd],9,2))); ........But I am still getting conversion failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit more tricky than your previous problem - [Fnd 2nd occourance of a string in a Memo Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903227/fnd-2nd-occourance-of-a-string-in-a-memo-field)

Traveling bottom up, use `StrReverse` function.

```
? StrReverse("Hello World!")
!dlroW olleH
```

However if you wish to search a particular String's starting position, then you can use the `InStrRev`  function,

```
? InStrRev("Hello World! It is a wonderful day. It truly is", "It")
 37 
? InStr("Hello World! It is a wonderful day. It truly is", "It")
 14
```

The error you have is because Mid returns a String, but my understanding is that the field EmailDate is a Date type. So you need to wrap it using `CDate` or `CDbl` function to treat it as Date.

Comment: I tried to wrap it using Cdate and I am getting all kind of syntax error. Would you be able to assist me with it.

Comment: Could you please Edit your post? So I can see what you have done. Along with the full explanation of all the kinds of error you are getting.

Comment: ok, so I grabbed the date into another field "TempD" and formatted it properly with cdate to update my "Emaildate" field with it    :  UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.emaildate = cdate(Format(Right([tempd],4) & "/" & Mid([tempd],6,3) & "/" & Mid([tempd],9,2)));                                                    Before Formatting the the date looks like "Wed, Nov 26, 2014"

Comment: But I am still getting Conversion error. Emaildate is a Date/Time field and TempD is a text field.

Comment: Again ! Edit your post with what you have done, for us to see it.

Comment: Probably you have a few trailing spaces. Try `Trim` before formatting the String.